# How is an Event stored in Axon EventStore?

Tags: spring, cqrs, axon

The following example implements event sourcing (and CQRS) with spring using Axon.

https://github.com/dashsaurabh/event-sourcing-cqrs-axon-spring-boot

Article regarding the code:

http://progressivecoder.com/event-sourcing-and-cqrs-with-axon-and-spring-boot-part-2//

In the application:

- a *JPA repository* stores the actual state of an Entity
- Events are stored in a seperate *EventStore*.

I'm having a hard time understanding how in the example, an Event is stored inside the EventStore. In **AccountQueryServiceImpl**, an **EventStore** is created and used to read the events from. But how is the EventStore populated exactly? (The service class is called by a REST Endpoint)

In regards to the JPA repository **accountRepository**, a new Account is persisted by using the *save()* method in **AccountQueryEntityManager** whenever a BaseEvent is fired, but I can't find a line of code where something is being appended to the EventStore.

AccountQueryServiceimpl

```
@Service
public class AccountQueryServiceImpl implements AccountQueryService {

private final EventStore eventStore;

private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

public AccountQueryServiceImpl(EventStore eventStore, AccountRepository 
accountRepository) {
    this.eventStore = eventStore;
    this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
}

@Override
public List<Object> listEventsForAccount(String accountNumber) {
    return eventStore.readEvents(accountNumber).asStream().map( s -> 
s.getPayload()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public AccountQueryEntity getAccount(String accountNumber) {
    return accountRepository.findById(accountNumber).get();
}
}
```

AccountQueryEntityManager

```
@Component
public class AccountQueryEntityManager {

@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("accountAggregateEventSourcingRepository")
private EventSourcingRepository<AccountAggregate> accountAggregateEventSourcingRepository;

@EventSourcingHandler
void on(BaseEvent event){
persistAccount(buildQueryAccount(getAccountFromEvent(event)));
}


private AccountAggregate getAccountFromEvent(BaseEvent event){
return accountAggregateEventSourcingRepository.load(event.id.toString()).getWrappedAggregate().getAggregateRoot();
}

private AccountQueryEntity findExistingOrCreateQueryAccount(String id){
return accountRepository.findById(id).isPresent() ? accountRepository.findById(id).get() : new AccountQueryEntity();
}

private AccountQueryEntity buildQueryAccount(AccountAggregate accountAggregate){
AccountQueryEntity accountQueryEntity =     findExistingOrCreateQueryAccount(accountAggregate.getId());

accountQueryEntity.setId(accountAggregate.getId());
accountQueryEntity.setAccountBalance(accountAggregate.getAccountBalance());
accountQueryEntity.setCurrency(accountAggregate.getCurrency());
accountQueryEntity.setStatus(accountAggregate.getStatus());

return accountQueryEntity;
}

private void persistAccount(AccountQueryEntity accountQueryEntity){
accountRepository.save(accountQueryEntity);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't provide a primary part of your question via a link to an external source.  Put the code you have questions about right in your question, formatted properly as code.  If doing this is too much work or would involve too much code, then your question is likely too broad.  You need to provide something concise and to the point that asks a question without the reader having to go off and study a project on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Axon Framework aims to provide you easy building blocks to work with DDD, CQRS and Event Sourcing. Through this, a lot of plumbing is provided out of the box to make your life on that road as easy as possible.

What's good to note to get a grasp how this works, is to assuming the shared sample focuses on all three paradigms. In such a scenario, you'd use Events as the synchronizing means between the Command and Query side of your application (typically in the form of distinct models).

The Command side of the app would deal with business validation by handling commands and validating it's own state. As a result of that, an event will be published. This in a typical Axon application occurs from within the lifecycle of an Aggregate. To *not* have the framework user require to wire the `EventStore` or `EventBus` directly, with all the added complexity of making sure the event is stored with the right sequence, Axon provides the `AggregateLifecycle#apply(Object)` method.

Under the hood it's through this that the framework will be able to automatically find the `EventBus` used to publish the event on, which will end up in the `EventStore` too.

**Side notes**

- The sample you're referring to uses Axon 4. This is already pretty old, as 4.4.4 has been released recently. If you try it out, place use more recent samples as a guide line, like this [Hotel Demo](https://github.com/AxonIQ/hotel-demo) by AxonIQ.
- Any other specifics you'd like to know are pretty well documented in the [Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/). If you're gonna look into this further, I'd highly recommend to keep a tab open with the guide in place.
- There are some online videos to get you started with Axon as well. For those who prefer video material over text, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQb0g7zJCWrzkpxznSUkERw) YouTube channel. [This](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4O1nDpoa5KQkkApGXjKi3rzUW3II5pjm) series is an actual quick start which might be helpful too.

Comment: how I can have a health check on the axon project (I'm not using axon -server)? Which modules|blocks need to be checked?

Comment: Hi Sajad, no offense, but your questions is quite out of scope for the thread at hand. I would suggest you make a separate StackOverflow thread for health checks around Axon.

To keep the scope of the original question, I'll stick to just sharing some documentation. Check out the "Monitoring and Metrics" page of Axon's reference guide for more information: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/monitoring
If you have made a separate Stack Overflow thread, and it's labeled with Axon, I'll likely find it eventually.